# Try/Catch unordered map exception properly

Tags: c++, exception, boost, try-catch, unordered-map

i have got this:

```
// static enum of supported HttpRequest to match requestToString
static const enum HttpRequest {
    GET, 
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE,
    OPTIONS,
    HEAD,
    TRACE
};

// typedef for the HttpRequests Map
typedef boost::unordered_map<enum HttpRequest, const char*> HttpRequests;

// define the HttpRequest Map to get static list of supported requests
static const HttpRequests requestToString = map_list_of
    (GET,    "GET")
    (POST,   "POST")
    (PUT,    "PUT")
    (DELETE, "DELETE")
    (OPTIONS,"OPTIONS")
    (HEAD,   "HEAD")
    (TRACE,  "TRACE");
```

now if i call

```
requestToString.at(GET);
```

it´s ok, but if i call an key which is not present like

```
requestToString.at(THIS_IS_NO_KNOWN_KEY);
```

it gives a runtime exception and the whole process aborts..

whats the best way to prevent this? is there a pragma or what ever or should i "java-like" surround it with a try/catch block or what?

kindly alex

Comment: `static const enum`??? Does `static` and `const` mean anything in type definition?

Comment: dont think that const is actually needed in this case but whatever :-)

Comment: `static` and `const` on the `enum` are meaningless in this context. C++ is not Java. In C++ `enum`s are integer types with a restricted range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `at` if you want an exception if it's not found, and handle the exception somewhere if you don't want it to terminate the process; use `find` if you want to handle it locally:

```
auto found = requestToString.find(key);
if (found != requestToString.end()) {
    // Found it
    do_something_with(found->second);
} else {
    // Not there
    complain("Key was not found");
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the auto prefix doing? if i´m using find in my solution i´m getting this: error C2678: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @AlexTape: That deduces the variable's type from the expression used to initialise it. If you're not using C++11, then you'll have to write `boost::unordered_map<enum HttpRequest, const char*>::const_iterator` instead unfortunately (or make a shorter typedef for that).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unordered_map::find` to search for a key that may or may not be in the map.

`find` returns an iterator, which is either == end () if the key is not found, or "points to" a std::pair if the key was found.

Uncompiled code:

```
unordered_map < int, string > foo;
unordered_map::iterator iter = foo.find ( 3 );
if ( iter == foo.end ())
     ; // the key was not found in the map
else
     ; // iter->second holds the string from the map.
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id3723710-bb says:

Throws: An exception object of type `std::out_of_range` if no such element is present.

Comment: hm is there a way to declare this catch globally ? i use the .at many times on different locations and i dont want to blow my code up with it.. any ideas ?

Comment: @AlexTape: There's no "global" way to handle exceptions, apart from terminating the program, since there's no universal way to recover from arbitrary errors. Either avoid throwing them in the first place, or include them in your design, figuring out how to recover from them, and putting catch block(s) in the appropriate place(s).

Comment: @AlexTape Find the function called `main` and use something like this: `int main() { try { /* your code */ } catch(std::out_of_range) {return 1;} }`

Comment: @anatolyg hehe very nice answer :-) simple thoughts :-)

Comment: @Alex Tape: If you don't want to repeat the code, put it in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You may first use `unordered_map::find` or `unordered_map::count` to check if the key is present.

Comment: yes ok but both functions dont return the referenced string , or am i wrong ?